# Can I customize public key from elliptic-curve package node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, private, elliptic-curve

this.keyPair = ec.genKeyPair();

I use this line to get the keys, and the public key will be the address, but I want the user to make their own address for private blockchain reasons (address will use the public key that the user made, no random hash), can I make it happen? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible. Private keys should not be obtainable from the public key. If that were the case, anybody could find the private key and steal the user's money. So it should not be possible to create a private key from a public key. If anybody discovers how to create a private key from a public key, you will find out: everybody's money on blockchains will be stolen and you will have no privacy in SSL.